# Blocking router change on angular component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I would like to know, how to block a router change on a component in angular 5.

I'am using : https://afeld.github.io/bootstrap-toc/ on my angular application, but when I click on the table of content, it is changing the page, back to home page because the adress is changing for example: http://localhost/#usage is changing the route back to home page http://localhost/#home.

Is there a way to block the router change on my component to use the script bootrap-toc?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try to use the `canDeactivate` property when defining the route and check if it's a #hash anchor or a real route where you want to go to and either allow it or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **canActivate** Api to allow to route to the particular page or not. similarly you could use **canDeactivate** to block to route to the particular page.

Here is the solution:
https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate

Comment: Yes, but it will only block one route, but it will not allow to use the bootsrap-toc I think no?

Comment: it will not block only one route, but, It will block every route you want. use this code inside your app.module.ts file:  { path: 'add-tutor/:tutorNetworkId', loadChildren: 'app/modules/addTutor.module#AddTutorModule', canActivate: [LoggedIn] },
        { path: 'student-profile/:studentNetworkId', loadChildren: 'app/modules/studentProfile.module#StudentProfileModule', canActivate: [LoggedIn] },
        ,
        { path: 'register-user',  canActivate: [LoggedOut] },